# Applying scroll to specific section of flex container

Tags: css, tailwind-css

```
<div class="flex flex-grow h-full w-100">
  <div class="flex flex-col bg-white w-1/5">
    <div class="dates px-4">
      <p>Today</p>
      <p>Tomorrow</p>
      <p>Upcoming</p>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="projects flex-grow px-4">
      <p>Project 1</p>
      <p>Project 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <hr />
      <button class="outline-none py-2 border-gray-400 text-red-400 w-full">
        Add project
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main bg-gray-100 flex-grow">Hello</div>
  <div class="bg-white w-1/5">Hello</div>
</div>
```

In the above code, I want only the div with class `projects` to be scrollable while holding the `dates` and `footer` fixed on their places. how to do that using tailwind.css ?! I also want the div with class `main` to be scrollable vertically while holding the other two divs fixed on their places without scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds a bit like a common usage of [overflow-y](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y).

For example, you could add this `CSS` rule to your project's class:

```
.projects {
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

You can add this rule to whichever container you want to be scrollable - in this case vertically.

---

On the other, there is [overflow-x: scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) for horizontal scrolling, or [overflow: scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) for both (shorthand).

Answer (score 2):

According to [tailwind overflow guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/overflow#class-reference), you can use `.overflow-y-auto` for vertical scrolling.

e.g.
`<div class="projects flex-grow overflow-y-auto px-4">`

It's good that you have used `.flex-grow` otherwise you would have to give a max-height to the div.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="flex flex-grow h-full w-100">
  <div class="flex flex-col bg-white w-1/5">
    <div class="dates px-4">
      <p>Today</p>
      <p>Tomorrow</p>
      <p>Upcoming</p>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="projects h-auto overflow-x-auto flex-grow px-4">
      <p>Project 1</p>
      <p>Project 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <hr/>
      <button class="outline-none py-2 border-gray-400 text-red-400 w-full">
        Add project
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main bg-gray-100 flex-grow">Hello</div>
  <div class="bg-white w-1/5">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).